# How to change starting index of rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

How can I change starting index of rows in `DataGridView`? Eg. it should start from 8, not from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, I dont think you can change the starting index of the rows, but there is an easy solution

Everytime you want to do sth with the RowIndex, add simply e.g. 8

```
DataGridView1.Rows[(myIndex + 8)].DoSomething();
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it's easier to do something like this. Thanks!

Comment: Small tip: if this answered your question, you can set it as answer and other people see that they dont need to look into your question anymore. (:

Comment: Yes, I did. But I had to wait. There is a time limit before I could accept it as answer. I think it's about 10 min limit. Cheers!